# Use snarl for notifications in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

Could anyone point me to code samples on using Snarl as the notification system for a WPF app?

Comment: +1 Snarl??..i Growl... who Barks. :D.. sorry couldn't resist myself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using one of the examples at the following url? http://www.fullphat.net/developer/developerGuide/win32API/ExampleIncludes/index.html

it appears to be a language specific implementation so should work with either WPF or Windows Forms.

UPDATE: Old URL is outdated, new url: http://snarl.fullphat.net/

Comment: Great find. It's even better than I had hoped for!

Comment: The link Says
Not Found

The requested URL /developer/developerGuide/win32API/ExampleIncludes/index.html was not found on this server.